# Software management tool for cluster

Tags: linux, cloud, distributed-computing

I have a cluster of about 20 computer where Linux is installed as OS. Now when I have to install a software on cluster, I have to install it on each system one by one. Is there any Linux tool GUI or CLI based that can do this job for all systems in cluster ? or any other solution ?. I want to control it at a single point.

Comment: Simple solution is to write a script in one computer. And make rest of machines accessible(SSH access by public key) by this computer. Configure the script would be like provided command will execute in all machines via SSH access.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any configuration management tool like [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/), [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/), [Puppet](https://puppet.com/), [Chef](https://www.chef.io/chef/), etc.

You could also use containers and a scheduler like [Docker Swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/), [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) or [Apache Mesos](http://mesos.apache.org/).

Comment: These tools like Puppet, are configuration management (means configuration can be controlled at single point) but not software management tool ( so that I can install software on cluster from single point)

Comment: These tools indeed allows you to install software, operating system packages and application software, they were designed specifically for that.